# Multiple Stages on Same screen with different viewport LIBGDX

Tags: camera, libgdx, viewport, scene2d

I am trying to scale my application to work similar on various aspect ratios.

I read about viewport and camera. And came to a conclusion that I should use FitViewport for my game stage so that no asset is being stretched. And I will use some background image to fill the black bars caused by fitviewport. But the problem is, whenever I use any other viewport than FitViewport for background image, the whole stage (both background and main stage) are being stretched, is there a way we can get away from black/white bar of FitViewport? I tried all the viewports for background namely StretchViewport, ScreenViewport, FillViewport.

Am I missing something very trivial? or is setting up multiple different viewport on same screen possible.

ps I was able to setup two same viewports with different size on same screen.
Here is the screen, I am getting after fitviewport. Notice the white bars on top and bottom which I am trying to eliminate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122006/4239538) worked for me. Just for reference

> You would need a second viewport, probably ExtendViewport with the
>   same virtual dimensions as your FitViewport.
>
> ```
> //create:
> fitViewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
> extendViewport = new ExtendViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
>
> //resize:
> fitViewport.update(width, height);
> extendViewport.update(width, height);
>
> //render:
>
> fitViewport.apply();
> batch.setProjectionMatrix(fitViewport.getCamera().combined);
> batch.begin();
> //draw game
> batch.end();
>
> extendViewport.apply();
> batch.setProjectionMatrix(extendViewport.getCamera().combined);
> batch.begin();
> //draw stuff in border
> batch.end();
> ```
>
> If you want to be sure the border stuff doesn't overlap your game, you
>   could swap the draw order above.
>
> Or you could just use ExtendViewport to begin with for everything.